# Send values from dataframe using send_keys() in Selenium using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a dataframe df. I am trying to send the values present in the column 'fruit' to the google translate page using `send_keys()` method in Selenium and python. Below is an example code that replicates what I am trying to do.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd

# Create a test dataframe
fruit = ['This is apple', 'This is orange', 'This is mango']
bucket = ['A', 'B', 'C']
df = pd.DataFrame({"fruit": fruit, "bucket": bucket})

# create a new Firefox session
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# Wait for the page to load
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

# Maximize the browser window
driver.maximize_window()

# navigate to the home page
driver.get("https://translate.google.co.in/")

# Locate the text field to update values
text_field = driver.find_element_by_name("text")

# Clears any value already present in text field
text_field.clear()

# Updates the string 'Breaking Bad' in search bar
text_field.send_keys(df['fruit'])
text_field.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Although it works, the rows are all being sent as a single line like this:

```
This is appleThis is orangeThis is mango
```

I want the values to appear in the google translate page like this:

```
This is apple
This is orange
This is mango
```

Any help on how to make this happen would be really appreciated. I have Python 3.6.6 and my selenium version is 3.141.0. My OS is Windows 10 (64 Bit).

Comment: When you tell it to send `df['fruit']`, it sends the entire column at once. You can loop through the column instead, sending each followed by a newline `'\n'` and then send enter

Comment: Is there any way to tell selenium webdriver that '\n' means a new line? Is there any way I can add a `'Control' + 'Shift'` command after every row is sent by send_keys() so that the lines stay separate? I am still learning this so please forgive me if these questions sound weird. I have tried looking for an answer but in vain. That's why as a last resort I have posted it out here so that the experts can guide me.

Comment: Selenium already *"knows"* that `'\n'` is a new-line character, so if to use code `send_keys('foo\nbar')` string will appear in textarea splitted into two sub-strings

Comment: `'\n'` _is_ a newline character, at least in most character encodings, and it should be read as such. And never apologize for asking honest questions, that's why this site exists and that's how you learn.

Comment: Sorry i had a typo in my previous comment. I actually wanted to say 'Shift' + 'Enter' for new line. I saw your solution and just replied to it too.

Comment: FYI... `driver.implicitly_wait(5)` doesn't actually wait for the page to load. What it does it sets the default wait time for implicit waits that last the life of `driver`. So from then on, any time you go to access an element on the page it will wait up to 5s for the element. See [the docs](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits) for more info. It's not a good practice to use implicit waits. If you look at the Selenium contributors, they recommend against it. You should use `WebDriverWait` instead.

Comment: Really appreciate your inputs and guidance @JeffC. I will surely look into `WebDriverWait`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to send concatenated string as

```
text_field.send_keys(" ".join(df['fruit']))
```

or with new-line characters:

```
text_field.send_keys("\n".join(df['fruit']))
```

P.S. Instead of using Selenium to translate strings you can use [GoogleTranslateAPI python binding](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/):

In Terminal/CommandLine:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/BoseCorp/py-googletrans.git
```

In Python shell/IDE:

```
from googletrans import Translator

translator = Translator()
#  Translate into "es" (Spanish)
print(translator.translate(" ".join(df['fruit']), dest='es').text)
```

Comment: I used the solution `text_field.send_keys("\n".join(df['fruit']))` which you had provided and it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot for helping me out!!

Comment: And that google translate page was just for highlighting my problem and not really meant for any translations.. :-)

Comment: @Code_Sipra , oh, I see :) But if in a future you will need translator, note that `googletrans.py` work flawlessly :))

Comment: Noted. Thanks again!